# Package Installation Error in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

When I try to create new cross platform xamarin form project then I get "**Package Installation Error**". I am using **Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3**.
I have already tried
1. Update "Visual studio tools for xamarin".
2. Repair Visual studio

Please suggest me, how to solve this problem.

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your project is currently targeting Android 6.0 but Android Support libraries v**25.x** require that you set your **target framework** (`compileSdkVersion`) to at least API 24 (Android 7.0) Nougat.

```
MonoAndroid 7.0:

Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable (= 25.4.0.2)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI (= 25.4.0.2)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 25.4.0.2)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment (= 25.4.0.2)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat (= 25.4.0.2)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable (= 25.4.0.2)
```

re: [Understanding Android API Levels](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/)

FYI: Open the Android SDK Manager and ensure that you have at least API-24's SDK installed, while you are there, install 25/26 and update the build tools and the rest of the SDK tool items

Comment: How to change target framework? When I create new project then it starts giving error and andoid & ios project are not loading in solution.

Comment: @AmarMathur In your `Xamarin.Android` application project options / `Build` / `General`, you can set the `Target Framework` there. I am *assuming* you have the Android SDKs installed for those APIs (24/25/26), if not open the Android SDK manager and install them

Comment: Xamarin.Android project is not creating due to these errors.

Comment: After updating Android sdk & libraries it is working. Thanks

Comment: @fedeteka Only the Android SDK manager and install any updates and new API versions

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks!